# Reading Outlook .msg in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, outlook

I am having problems trying to read an Outlook Email (Unicode) .msg file in Perl. Every other day i get an E-Mail with information which i have to put into another File. I'd like to automate this process.

Basically i have limited programming skills and have just started to learn Perl specifically for this task.

This is the part of my program trying to read the mail. So far did the Email::Outlook::Message from [perlmonks](http://search.cpan.org/~mvz/Email-Outlook-Message-0.918/lib/Email/Outlook/Message.pm) get me:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Email::Outlook::Message;
use Email::MIME;

my $sourceDir = "c:/temp";

open_msg("test.msg");

sub open_msg {
   my $verbose = 0;
   my $msgFile = shift;
   my $origMsg = new Email::Outlook::Message "$sourceDir/$msgFile", $verbose or die "$!";
   my $mime = $origMsg->to_email_mime;
   $mime->as_string;
   return ($origMsg);
}
```

I am able to print the encoded hash, but i don't know how i can store the decoded text of the body in an array?

I am glad for every bit of help i can get.

Edit: i figured i change my initial question  a bit to avoid posting a nearly equal question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$mime->as_string` returns the value you want to print, but you don't do anything with it, and then instead print the unchanged `$mime` handle.  You want `print $mime->as_string;`

I believe the code should also display `Useless use of as_string in void context` or similar with `use warnings;`

Comment: Thanks, this takes me one step further. Now it seems as if the output is the encoded (...YXJlYXN0LWZvbn...) MIME part. How can i get it decoded?

Comment: Really a separate question.  Looks like `base64` but your snippet is too limited to really tell. http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html